# ImportError: cannot import name linsolve

Tags: python, scipy

I am testing a piece of Python code that contains the line:

```
from scipy import sparse, linsolve
```

When I run the script, I get the error:

```
    from scipy import sparse, linsolve
ImportError: cannot import name linsolve
```

A quick google search shows the code for linsolve.py (hosted on Koders.com). My question is:

Is linsolve a part of scilab - or do I need to download linsolve.py separately?

Comment: Linspace?  Is it yet another Jeremy Lin pun?

Comment: You have variously written linspace and linsolve in your question and title. Which are you actually trying to import?

Comment: @Anycom: uncanny, I was just reading about JL yesterday (never heard of him before!)

Comment: @talonmies: Ah, my bad .. I'll correct the title.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the code in question is actually trying to import `scipy.linsolve`, that was deprecated a long time ago, and may well have been remove from the latest versions of scipy. For compatibility you could try this:

```
from scipy import sparse
import scipy.sparse.linalg.dsolve as linsolve
```

that should give the code the `sparse` and `linsolve` it relies on and shouldn't require any other modifications (unless there is something inside linsolve it relies on which has also changed, of course).